# plotting bivariate normal distribution samples

Tags: r, data-visualization, multivariate-normal-distribution, bivariate, multivariate-distribution

I have generated two samples $\underline{X_i}$ and $\underline{Z_i}$

$\underline{X_1}$ $\underline{X_2}\dots \underline{X_{5000}}$ , while $\underline{X_i} \sim N_2[(1,2)^T,\begin{pmatrix}2&1.5\\ 1.5&2\end{pmatrix}]$.

$\underline{Z_1}$ $\underline{Z_2}\dots \underline{Z_{5000}}$ , while $\underline{Z_i} \sim N_2[(0,0)^T,I_2]$

by generating

```
n1 <- 5000
mu <- c(0,0)
sigma <- diag(2)
y2 <- mvrnorm(n1,mu,sigma)
```

and then applying linear transformation on $z_1\dots z_{5000}$
to generate $x_1\dots x_{5000}$.

how to make a 2d-density plot and  scatter plot of the data $X $ and $Z$
because now I have two columns for each sample.

[image]

Comment: $X_i$ and $Z_i$ are both 2x1 random vectors, i.e. $X_i=[X_{i1},X_{i2}]^T$ hence you can only plot a 2D density, i.e. $PDF(X_{i1},X_{i2})$. That fills up 3 dimensions. The joint distribution of $X_i$ and $Z_i$ would be a 4D density, hence you would need 5 dimensions.

Comment: Yes this is why I got confused , it seems like I understood the question wrong and I need to plot $X_i$ only and I know how to do it.
I'm going to delete the question , thanks for your help